# Spring Service enable flag location

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I'm creating Spring services that are optional,Therefore I keep adding specific Utility class/method for check if service is enabled, e.g.

```
if (ThisServiceUtil.isThisServiceEnabled()) { // then call service
```

Internally I check property derived from DB/ property file

Is there a better way to check if service is enabled file/DB driven? (without adding classes/methods every time)

Should I add dummy service (do nothing) in case service not enabled and just call service methods without checking?

Comment: @WildDev can you answer with more details a better solution?